# modifying global javascript variables and accessing them in the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to fiddling with javascript - but here is what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have code like such:

```
    $('#numberItems').keyup(function () {
      var num = parseInt($(this).val());
      var price = parseInt($('#price').text());
      var.cost = num * price
      $('#total').text(cost);
    }).keyup();
```

This really works fine for what I'm doing - but what I'd like to do is take the cost variable and stick it in a link - such as:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/<script>document.write(cost)</script>">Googly</a>
```

I realize, to make the variable global, I need to stick outside of the function, but then how do my calculations save to it?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance: what's the use of putting a variable in a true url? Is this, by any chance, something that you are trying to achieve for google checkout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not actually need to make the variable global, unless you are accessing it elsewhere. If you want the URL change to occur when a user changes the element with id numberItems, You are actually going to need to add an ID attribute to that A element, then use javascript to update the HREF attribute.

```
<a id="aElementToChange" href="http://www.google.com/<script>document.write(cost)</script>">Googly</a>
```

And the javascript (after your $('#total').text(cost); line):

```
var aElementToChange = document.getElementById("aElementToChange");
aElementToChange.setAttribute("href", "http://www.google.com/" + cost);
```

You can change the javascript to jquery as you need.

Comment: is it possible to just add to the URL rather than set the entire thing?

Comment: yes, I believe so by doing a setAttribute("href", aElementToChange.getAttribute("href") + cost); You see the inherit issue with though, as every time they type, it will multiply like babies :)

Answer (score 0):

At the top level of your script file, outside of any document.ready() handler, add this:

```
var cost;
```

Then, you can reference it anywhere by just not declaring it with `var` like this:

```
$('#numberItems').keyup(function () {
  var num = parseInt($(this).val());
  var price = parseInt($('#price').text());
  cost = num * price
  $('#total').text(cost);
}).keyup();
```

You can't use that variable with `document.write()` because `document.write()` can only be used while the document is being parsed and your `cost` variable isn't initialized before the document is loaded.  Using `document.write()` after the document has been loaded  causes the current document to get wiped out and a new document started.

You can use the `cost` variable to set an `href` dynamically (after the document has been loaded) like this:

```
<a id="myLink" href="http://www.google.com/">Googly</a>

$("#myLink").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/" + cost);
```

Notice that you just use string math to add cost into an existing string.

Or, you could use jQuery to create a link from scratch, set it's href and insert it into your page.

Comment: you forgot quotes around `href` and you have an extra " after cost :)

Answer (score 0):

Stay away from global variables !! xD

They are the easiest solution to all problems but they will cause you a lot of hard time 
later if you upgrade your code!

As being said, add an `id` attribute to the `<a>` tag
Then simply add `$("#id_you_added").attr("href","<a href='http://www.google.com/"+cost+"'>Googly</a>");` in the code above so that it gets modified dynamically

I hope this helps